# "integer argument expected, got float" ERROR

Tags: python, opencv, artificial-intelligence, python-3.9

I'm doing a checkers game in python with OpenCV and I have one error:

```
integer argument expected, got float
```

I don't understand why. The line that give me error is:

```
cv2.circle(frameToDraw, (tuple(shapeTarget.center)), 10, (0, 0, 255), 1)
```

My full code is here:

```
 def drawShapes(self, shapeTargets, **kwargs):  #RETURNS A FRAME WITH THE SHAPES DRAWN ON IT
    """
    Draws circles on every center of the shapes in the shapeArray
    frameToDraw: What frame to draw on top of.
    """

    frameToDraw = kwargs.get('frameToDraw', self.vid.frame.copy())
    color       = kwargs.get('color', (0, 255, 0))

    for shapeTarget in shapeTargets:
        if hasattr(shapeTarget, 'center'):
            cv2.circle(frameToDraw, (tuple(shapeTarget.center)), 10, (0, 0, 255), 1)
            cv2.polylines(frameToDraw, [np.asarray(shapeTarget.vertices)], True, color, 4)

    return frameToDraw
```

Can anyone help me to solve this problem, so I can finish my project?

Comment: Most likely here in the tuple ```(tuple(shapeTarget.center))``` you have ```float``` values, but there should be ```int```. Here is one of the solutions ```(tuple(map(int, shapeTarget.center)))```

Comment: "I dont understand why." -- then do some debugging. It's not like that's too much work, given that only one of the parameters to that function could potentially be a culprit... probably less time than it took to write this question up (i.e. add `print(shapeTarget.center)` and see what that shows you).

Comment: @crackanddie I have already tried your suggestion, but an error coming again that said "circle() missing required argument 'radius' (pos 3)". I'm pretty sure that i have already input the radius. What do you think my  mistake? Am i missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Try unpacking the position's x and y coordinates, and then passing the into a tuple with `int` wrappers:

```
cv2.circle(frameToDraw, (tuple(shapeTarget.center)), 10, (0, 0, 255), 1)
```

with

```
x, y = shapeTarget.center
cv2.circle(frameToDraw, (int(x), int(y)), 10, (0, 0, 255), 1)
```